# Save <select> tag for on next page load - SharePoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint

So I am currently editing my Team SharePoint site using SharePoint designer, the current issue I have is that we have a team Rota that I would like to be able to change and it save on the page for the next time that anyone goes on to that page.

Currently I have this:

```html
<select id="sectionid" size="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Person 1</option>
  <option value="1">Person 2</option>
  <option value="2">Person 3</option>
  <option value="3">Person 4</option>
</select>
```

I am sadly not the best at JavaScript coding, but with SharePoint I was expecting to be able to use the edit and save function to interchange the values as default until changed on edit again, any idea's on how I go about this?

If there is already a question and answer on something like this could you point me to it, I searched for a good 10 minutes trying to find a similar situation.

Comment: Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Do you have access to localStorage or cookies?

Comment: Hi, Sorry i don't believe i do have access to the localStorage, I am only able to work on this on Friday's as well so i will apologies in advance if i am slow with responding.

Comment: In regards to the localStorage again, I should now have access to this, will give a few tests to this however still unsure of how to write up in code for this. I have looked at sessionStorage as testing for localStorage. i have been looking at this page as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453532/select-onchange-reload-the-page-and-keep-the-selected-option